# how to import java packages in a java core Jupyter Notebook

Tags: java, jupyter-notebook, package, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to execute java code from a github repository in google colab,I know that google colab is for python by default so I installed [the ijava library](https://github.com/SpencerPark/IJava) on to the Jupyter notebook using the commands:

```
!wget https://github.com/SpencerPark/IJava/releases/download/v1.3.0/ijava-1.3.0.zip
!unzip  ijava-1.3.0.zip
!python install.py --sys-prefix
```

after I changed the Jupyter notebook configurations as follows:

```
{
  "nbformat": 4,
  "nbformat_minor": 0,
  "metadata": {
    "colab": {
      "name": "example.ipynb",
      "provenance": []
    },
    "kernelspec": {
      "name": "python3"--->"java",
      "display_name": "python3"--->"java"
    },
    "language_info": {
      "name": "python"
    }
  },
  "cells": [
    {
      "cell_type": "code",
      "execution_count": null,
      "metadata": {
        "id": "NzKT3-VExE4i"
      },
      "outputs": [],
      "source": [
        ""
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

After these changes I was able to run java in that Jupyter notebook, so I put this ipynb file inside my java netbeans project in the same package as my main file but when I try to import a package from that project I get an error that the package isn't defined, so how can I import packages from my java github repo inside the ipynb file?

Comment: Try [modifying the classpath](https://github.com/SpencerPark/IJava#configuring) to find the packages.

Comment: I uploaded my java project to google drive then mounted my drive to google colab then installed ijava package using the following command `python install.py --classpath '/content/drive/Othercomputers/My Laptop/Master_Project/src'` but it didn't work , do I need to do something else? @AliasCartellano